# How can I subtract 1 column from another in R based on 2 aggregate columns

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-manipulation

[First Data frame 'total_coming_in' column names: 'LocationID','PartNumber',"Quantity"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg43G.png)

[Second Data frame 'total_going_out' column names: 'LocationID','PartNumber',"Quantity"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpkwz.png)

I want output as 'total_data'  column names: 'LocationID','PartNumber',"Quantity_subtract" where
Quantity_subtract = total_coming_in$Quantity - total_going_out$Quantity grouped for each  'LocationID','PartNumber'
I tried this :-

```
matchingCols <- c('LocationID','PartNumber')
mergingCols <- names(coming_in)[3]
total_coming_in[total_going_out,on=matchingCols, 
                                lapply(
                                  setNames(mergingCols),
                                  function(x) get(x) - get(paste0("i.", x))
                                ),
      nomatch=0L,
      by=.EACHI
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` as you seem to want to, I would first cleanly merge the two tables and then do the substract operation on just the rows that make sense (i.e. for rows in `total_coming_in` which have matching values values in `total_going_out` and vice-versa):

```
library(data.table)
M <- merge(total_coming_in, total_going_out, by = c('LocationID','PartNumber'))   
# i.e. all.x = FALSE, all.y = FALSE, 
# thereby eliminating rows in x without matching row in y and vice-versa  
M[ , Quantity_subtract := Quantity.x - Quantity.y, 
     by = c('LocationID','PartNumber')]
```

Now for completenes, as your question might be interpreted as allowing 0 values for Quantity.y in `total_going_out` for rows of `total_coming_in` that have no matching values in `total_going_out` and vice-versa, you could do in this case:

```
 M <- merge(total_coming_in, total_going_out, all = TRUE, by = c('LocationID','PartNumber'))   
# i.e. all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE, 
# thereby allowing rows in x without matching row in y and vice-versa    

M[is.na(Quantity.x), Quantity.x := 0]
M[is.na(Quantity.y), Quantity.y := 0]
M[ , Quantity_subtract := Quantity.x - Quantity.y, 
     by = c('LocationID','PartNumber')]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a column that gives you the difference of `total_coming_in` and `total_going_out` for each combination of `PartNumber` and `LocationID`, correct?

If so, the following will do:

```
library(dplyr)
matchingCols <- c("LocationID", "PartNumber")
total_data <- full_join(total_coming_in, total_going_out, by=matchingCols)
total_data <- mutate(total_data, Quantity_subtract = Quantity.x - Quantity.y)
total_data <- select(total_data, -Quantity.x, -Quantity.y) #if you want to get rid of these columns
```

I used this example data:

```
total_coming_in <- list(LocationID = round(runif(26, 1000, 9000)),
                        PartNumber = paste(runif(26, 10000, 20000), LETTERS, sep="-"),
                        Quantity = round(runif(26, 2, 4))
                        ) %>% as_tibble()
random_integers <- sample(1:26,26,FALSE)
total_going_out <- list(LocationID = total_coming_in$LocationID[random_integers],
                        PartNumber = total_coming_in$PartNumber[random_integers],
                        Quantity = round(runif(26, 1, 3))
                        ) %>% as_tibble()
```